# Resolving promises without a digest cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

AngularJS promises seem to be tied to a digest cycle, as in, the success/error callbacks are not called until a digest cycle is run. This means that anything that uses promises, such as `$http` or manually created promises, also need to trigger a digest cycle in order to get the callbacks to run.

Is it possible to use promises in Angular, without the digest cycle being run at all? I realise you can use `$applyAsync`, which schedules the digest cycle for a bit later, but I'm looking to not run the digest cycle at all, and still have the `then` callbacks run.

Essentially I'm trying to work out how to squeeze as much performance as possible from an app that would use a fair bit of asynchronous behaviour that would need promises resolved but not necessarily the digest cycle run.

Comment: Did you really identify that digest cycle as having a performance cost ? Deferring the continuation call is a fundamental property of promises and doesn't seem to be costly in other implementations (I don't know AngularJS promises).

Comment: @dystroy I haven't identified it as having a very high performance cost, as the app doesn't exist yet. However, even if it takes 10ms (and in previous apps they can take longer than that), and I have 10 promises resolving in 1 second (each triggered by separate events), that ends up with 100ms of time taken per second of needless digest cycle running, which does seem like it can enter the territory of the user being able to notice, especially as it reduces the time available to do other processing.

Comment: So use native promises then.

Comment: @dfsq That has crossed my mind, I may end up doing that. In an ideal case though, I would use one promise implementation, just to reduce the different APIs used in the code.

Comment: Promises don't wait 10 ms to be continued. You may use Bluebird which currently appears to be faster than native ones.

Comment: @dystroy I know the 10ms isn't from promises itself, but rather the fact that Angular requires the digest cycle run in order for its promise success/error callbacks to be run. As you say, native or Bluebird may be the way to go.

Comment: A "digest" is actually a poll of a bunch of `$watch` methods, and those methods will do nothing (at least nothing seriously time consuming) if there are no (DOM) changes to be made - and the way to ensure that is not to have made any `$scope` assignments. So, I wonder if a more realistic approach might be to live with the naturally occurring digest cycle, but to somehow defer `$scope` assignments until you are ready for the digest cycle to actually handle your asynchronously derived data - at that point make the assignments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible. Whenever a `then` handler runs it schedules the callback via `$evalAsync` which schedules a digest if one is not already scheduled.

The exception to this is `$timeout` that accepts an extra argument to not run a digest. On the other hand - multiple promises that resolve in the same turn run on the same digest.

Your options are:
 - Use XMLHttpRequqest directly, seriously - it's not very hard. The biggest downside to this is that it will not respect interceptors and other $http hooks (like the mock backend).
 - Decorate `$q` to not schedule via `$evalAsync` or add a `.thenNoDigest` method to the promise prototype that schedules via `setTimeout`.
 - Use a userland promise library instead of $q for $http or over XHR.

Comment: Using something other than `$q` sounds like the most likely option.

Comment: @Adam honestly I'm not sure that there are a lot of cases where digests are more expensive than a network requests.