# Using callbacks instead of promises in AngularJS results in different behavior in unit tests. Why?

Tags: angularjs, callback, scope, synchronization, promise

I'm testing a $resource. If I have code like this:

```
$resource.do(stuff).$promise.then(function(data){
 console.log(1);
});
console.log(2);
```

I get the print out:

```
2
1
```

But if I have code like this:

```
var callback = function(data){
console.log(1);
}

$resource.do(stuff,callback);
console.log(2);
```

I get the print out:

```
1
2
```

Why? I have found that with the second method, I do not need to call $rootScope.$apply() to get the correct output from my unit test (instead of console.log(2), I return a variable). Using the first method, I have to call $rootScope.$apply() in my unit test in order to get output. I thought that passing callbacks is the same as calling .then on a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is called as soon as the `$resource` finishes what it is doing. This doesn't have to be in the Angular digest cycle. The promise is resolved in the angular digest cycle. When you call `$rootScope.$apply()`

For more see: [Resolving promises without a digest cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428629/resolving-promises-without-a-digest-cycle)

Comment: This sounds right. Very interesting, thanks. How do you know that callbacks are called without waiting for the Angular digest cycle? I can't find this info anywhere.

Comment: I don't know with absolute certainty. But it is what callbacks generally are supposed to do and it fits your observations. To see if that actually happens you'd have to check the implementation of the `$resource.do` function. Maybe step through it with the debugger.